# Create Layout Dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I want to create this [image: this] kind of layout that can work for all device(different screen size).

I am trying to inflate single row multiple times according to the device size here is the code:-

```
  private void get_device_size() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    for (int i = 0; i < width / 20; i++) {
        Log.e("i", String.valueOf(i));
        setup_scroller(i, width / 20);
    }
}

private void setup_scroller(int i, int total) {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_line_scroller_single_row, null);
    LinearLayout linear_line = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear_line);
    if (i == total / 2) {
        linear_line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    } else if (i == (total - 2) / 2) {
        linear_line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color_green));
    } else if (i == (total - 3) / 2) {
        linear_line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color_green));
    } else if (i == (total + 2) / 2) {
        linear_line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color_green));
    } else if (i == (total + 4) / 2) {
        linear_line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color_green));
    } else {
        linear_line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color_green_alpha));
    }
    linear_line_Scroller.addView(v);
}
```

layout_line_scroller_single_row:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linear_line"
android:layout_width="2dp"
android:layout_height="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/base_color_green"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting following output [image: this output]form this code.
I want highlighted lines in the center of the screen for all screen size devices.

Thanks!

Comment: i do not see any dynamically created layout in your code. Mind rephrasing your question to reflect what it really is about? also show your xml as it should automatically scale, so your math should be not needed.

Comment: I am trying to inflate single row multiple times, I have added XML code also. Please check.

Comment: This is very ineffective. I'd consider creating custom view instead

Comment: okay, I can create a customize view (green line), but how I can set highlighted lines in the center for all devices(different screen sizes)?

Comment: You measure your view and then draw it. Once you got it measured you know its size. So you know where's the middle. Then you add some logic in your `onDraw()` to make it look as you want.

Comment: okey, i will try this. Thanks